# Vim: How to highlight code inside #ifdef - #endif block?

Tags: vim

I usually write my debugging code inside an `ifdef-endif` block. The block is turned on by a macro, which is named in a certain way: Eg. `DRAW_DEBUG`, `TOPO_DEBUG`, `MTS_DEBUG` - i.e., all debug code is controlled by some macro ending with '`_DEBUG`'. Thus, a typical debug code-block looks like this:

```
#ifdef DRAW_DEBUG
    //Do something
    // Do something else
#endif
```

I want to highlight all such debug code blocks in Vim. It should be easy to do since such blocks are easy to identify. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you only want those blocks to stand out or do you have any further motive?

Comment: @romainl: That is all I want!

Answer (score 1):

You can take this snippet as a starting point:

```
" define an highlighting for your special region
highlight Foo ctermbg=16 guibg=#000000

" define your region
syntax region Foo start=/^\s*#ifdef.*_DEBUG/ end=/^\s*#endif/
```

Make sure you read `:help syntax` and more specifically `:help syn-region`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin: [ifdef-highlighting](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=7)

Copy file to `$HOME/.vim/syntax/`

Then create file `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` with content `source $HOME/.vim/syntax/ifdef.vim`

After open cpp file, you can run `:Undefine DRAW_DEBUG` to highlight this define block.

Of cource you can edit `ifdef.vim` for your needs.